# Reversing exponents

Tags: logarithms, exponentiation

First, I want to apologize if this is a duplicate, but I couldn't find an answer when searching for it. So, I know that in the equation $x^y=z$, to find $y$ you could do $\frac{ln(z)}{ln(x)}$. However, I was wondering if there is a way to find $x$ using $z$, or moreover if you could find both $x$ and $y$ using only z. Thanks in advance!

Comment: $2^6=4^3=8^2=64$; knowing only $z=64$, which of these $(x,y)$ you want to find?

Comment: @IvanNeretin personally, all of them would be fine

Comment: Are you dealing with _integer_ numbers only?

Comment: @IvanNeretin yes, integers only

Comment: Then [factorize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization) your $z$, as in $z=p_1^{\alpha_1}\cdot\dots\cdot p_k^{\alpha_k}$, where $p_1,\dots,p_k$ are some primes and $\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_k$ are some integer exponents, find the greatest common divisor of those exponents (say, $d$), and go with that. Any divisor of $d$ (including $d$ itself) is a valid $y$ for you.

Comment: Ah, okay. Thanks